# Connect to AWS EC2 through SFTP using non root user

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, sftp, ubuntu-18.04

I can connect through SSH and SFTP with the regular root user provided: ubuntu

I created another user and I'm trying to connect through SFTP and it's not letting me, this user has a password. So when I go to connect I use the private key and the name of the user but it doesn't log on. What's the steps to remediate this?

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: It doesn't tell me anything @MichaelHampton. I looked at auth.log and syslog

Comment: If it doesn't tell you anything, then you did not even connect to that server. Please give some details that might indicate what the problem is. Right now your question has absolutely nothing useful.